# Doctrine2: Why is Mapping not detecting my composite keys

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two tables/entities `client` and `site` that have a many to many relationship combined by a join table `client_site`. Here are how my entities are setup.

**Here is the client table entity**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="client")
 */
class Client
{
    /** 
     * @Id @Column(type="bigint")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Site", inversedBy="clients")
     * @JoinTable(name="client_site",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="c_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="s_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $sites;
```

**And the site table entity**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="site")
 */
class Site
{
    /** 
     * @Id @Column(type="bigint")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Client", mappedBy="sites")
     */
    private $clients;
```

**This is the client_site table entity**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="client_site",indexes={@index(name="FK_client_site",columns={"c_id"}),@index(name="FK_client_site_2",columns={"s_id"})})
 */
class ClientSite
{
    /**
     * @Id 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="ClientSite")
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @Id 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site", inversedBy="ClientSite")
     */
    private $site;
```

**This is the query I am trying to run**

```
$query = Zend_Registry::get('em')
                    ->createQuery('SELECT c, s  
                    FROM Application\Models\Client c
                    JOIN c.sites s 
                    WHERE c.is_active = 1');            
$clients = $query->getResult();
```

**And this is my error**

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity 'Application\Models\ClientSite'. Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

I put the @Id on both fields in the ClientSite entity, as they are the composite primary keys for my joiner table. Can this not be done in Doctrine2? If it can't, what are my alternative options.

If you CAN do this, what have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently supported by Doctrine 2.

However, they are [working on adding support for this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/dc2-experimental-associations-id-fields) in an experimental branch. Apparently this might be included in the 2.1 release if it works without issues.

Comment: do you know if this is fixed now?

Comment: @user1121883 I haven't been following the development lately, you should be able to easily test whether it works yourself though.